# unusual (non-local) differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not even know how the following class of equations is named:
$y'(x)=\frac{1}{x}y(x) - \frac{2}{x}y(\frac{x}{2})$.
I'm looking for a solution in the domain $x\ge1$, with $y(1)=1$.

What should I search for? Any hint how to tackle it?

Comment: substitute $t=\frac{x}{2}$ and tell me what you see

Comment: It's called a [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation).

Comment: Set $u(t)=y(2^t)$, then $u'(t)=y'(2^t)\ln2·2^t=\ln2·(u(t)-2u(t-1))$ which is a delay-differential equation.

Comment: Thanks to you all. @RobertIsrael now I know what to search for.

Comment: @LutzL this solves my problem. I was actually interested in the behavior at large values of x, which now translates into large values of t and the solution is $y(x)\propto 1/x$, found after approximating $u(t-1)\approx u(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is 
$$ y = x^a \cos(b \ln(x)) = \text{Re}(x^{a+ib})$$
where 
$$ a + i b = 1 + W(-\ln(2))/\ln(2) $$
and $W$ is any branch of the Lambert W function.  The first few $[a,b]$ pairs are approximately
$$[.1753214538, 1.567432123],\; [-2.515236722, 10.88005321],\; [-3.361431413, 20.08716280],\; [-3.888856646,29.22118551]$$

Comment: Thank you so much Robert, though I note that the solution you find does not agree with my reasoning leading to $y\approx x^{-1}$ at large values of $x$. Is anything wrong in my last comment above to @Lutzl?

Comment: Yes: the assumption $u(t-1) \approx u(t)$ is wrong.